# how to pass address(0x0) to remix?

Tags: remix, ether, erc-20

I want my users call a function and send some deposit to contract. I want them to chose whether they want to send ETH or ERC20 tokens. I have my code and I see no flaw in it. but how can I pass address(0x0) to remix UI? I mean if I want to send ETH, I need to set the token address to null or something.

if there is no option. is it possible to send address(0x0) using truffle?

```
contract SendEtherOrToken {

 function send(uint _value, Token _currency) public payable {
    if (address(_currency) == address(0x0)) { 
        require(msg.value == _value, "ETH value doesn't match offer");
    } 
    else { // use ERC20
        require(msg.value == 0, "ETH would be lost");
        require( _currency.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _value),  "transferFrom failed");
    }
  }
}
```

I know, I can use a fake address and provide that option in my UI in case of sending ETH.
if (_currency == fake address) {accept eth} and then pass the fake address in UI when user chose the ETH pay option instead of Token. but, I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer,
you have to pass the full length address to remix. even if it is an address or 0x0

in this case it will be : 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000